# what is inner equijoin?

Tags: sql, linq

Can someone please give me a simple explanation of an inner equijoin?

I'm finding explanations found via google quite hard to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Join (SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))

> An equi-join, also known as an
>   equijoin, is a specific type of
>   comparator-based join, or theta join,
>   that uses only equality comparisons in
>   the join-predicate. *Using other
>   comparison operators (such as <)
>   disqualifies a join as an equi-join*.

These are joins where only equality operators are used.

Eg.

```
SELECT *
FROM   employee 
       INNER JOIN department 
          ON employee.DepartmentID = department.DepartmentID
```

Comment: i like how OP found "explanations found via google" hard to understand, but an exact paste from wikipedia (the first search match for "inner equijoin" on google) to be quite comprehensible =) but hey, it's correct and all, so you've got my +1

Answer (score 2):

An inner equijoin is simply an inner join that only uses the equality operator (no < or >) in the join predicate.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://programming.top54u.com/post/SQL-Inner-Equi-Join-Examples.aspx) is a good explanation:

> Equi Join: Equi Join returns all the
>   columns from both tables and filters
>   the records satisfying the matching
>   condition specified in Join “ON”
>   statement of sql inner join query.

```
USE NORTHWIND

SELECT * FROM CATEGORIES C INNER JOIN
PRODUCTS P ON P.CATEGORYID = C.CATEGORYID
```

Equi join is the join which contains an equal operator in its join condition.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the simple join on a column (or columns) between two tables when the values in the columns must match (ie are equal) and there must be a row in both tables in order for a row to end up in the resultset.

eg

```
   create table departments( department_id number, department_name varchar2(30))
   create table employees (employee_id number, employee_name varchar2(30), department_id number)


   select d.department_name, e.employee_id
      from employees e
      inner join departments d
      on (d.department_id = e.department_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

inner equijoin is simple inner join that uses only equality comparisons in the join-predicate

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Equi-join